# NodeJS MongoDB locks on documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, locking

I am using the mongodb driver and am concerned about possible concurrency issues that could duplicate objects. Reading a few questions and answers on stack overflows I believe that writes operations are atomic, but this may not solve my concurrency problem. Let's say there are two concurrent calls to `doSomeAndDelete` with the same `id`: operations in `HERE` might take some time but only one of these two functions should be able to handle `result`. How can I implement a lock?

```js
async function doSomeAndDelete(id){

const result = await myCollection.findOne({ _id : id });

/*Some operations on result [HERE]*/

if(/*conditions*/)
  await myCollection.deleteOne({ _id : id});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deletion, only one of the operations will succeed and delete the document, while the other one will not delete anything because the document no longer exists. That, assuming, the `_id` will not be reused.

In general, write operations on a document are atomic, so if you have multiple threads writing to a document, you might want to use mongodb transactions, or use some form of optimistic locking. For example, you can use an ObjectId field in your documents as a version id, and use a new value for each update. When you read-and-update a document, you validate that the field has the same value you obtained from the read, meaning the record has not been modified since you read it.

Comment: I try to explain my problem in detail by trying to give an example: I have an object for sale and two people try to buy it at the same time. I cannot remove the object as soon as I fetch it from the database, because if the payment is not successful I have to allow it to the other. What do you think would be the most efficient way to make such a construct? I'm new to asynchronous programming and maybe I'm missing some concept. I would like to search by myself but I probably don't understand which question is right. Thanks for the reply, the informations you gave me are useful.

Comment: There are multiple ways you can solve this. You can "reserve" it when someone claims it, so someone else cannot. If the payment fails or the claiming party doesn't do anything with it, you should timeout after a while. You can avoid race conditions using the methods I described.

Comment: I understand what you mean. What would be a safe and efficient way to do this? Thinking about it, I could use a mutex inside the document, but it seems like a waste of storage.

Comment: You can't use a mutex for db storage. Use transactions for read-update-write scenarios.